# How can I pass a value to a button in Ionic/Angular?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework

**I know that the name and value attributes cannot bind to a button,but what's the solution?
I'm trying to do this:**

```
 <ion-button type="submit" color="primary" style="text-align:center" ngModel value="{{data.id}}" name="follower_id">
      follow
 </ion-button>
```

**It's not a form it's just an ion-card that returns some data from the server, and now I have to pass one of these data by clicking on the button bcuz I have another server function that needs this data in particular, this data is the id and it's not a constant integer, each ion-card has a different ID
HELP ME PLEAAASE :(**

Comment: I presume this is for Angular 2+, not AngularJS (v1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (click)="follow(data.id)" inside button

And in ts file create follow function to handle button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Like @aarej said in his answer, use `(click)="follow(data.id)"` on the button to trigger `follow` function in the component.

Example code for the component:

```
public follow(id: string): void {
    this.http.get(`sample.url?id=${id}`).subscribe(done => console.log(done));
}
```

Ideally you would provide a https://stackblitz.com/ example as there are a lot of missing code in the question.

Comment: I'm afraid it's against stackoverflow policy to provide help to a single user. As you understand this is database of answers that potentially can help someone else. If we take this offline, how is it going to help anyone else?

Best I can offer is to simplify your code that it doesn't disclose anything private.